# Select multiple values from a json array in plsql

Tags: arrays, json, plsql

I want to select value from a json array. Eg:
The data is in table Data in column name json_col

```
{
    "ABlock": {
        "fruits1": [{
            "Frt1": "Apple",
            "Clr1": "Red",
            "Qty1": "14"
        }, {
            "Frt1": "Grapes",
            "Clr1": "Black",
            "Qty1": "7"
        }],
        "fruits2": [{
            "Frt2": "Pear",
            "Clr2": "Green",
            "Qty2": "9"
        }, {
            "Frt2": "Lemon",
            "Clr2": "Yellow",
            "Qty2": "5"
        }]
    }
}
```

Here I want to select Qty1&Qty2.
The code I tried to select just Qty1 is

```
Select json_value(json_col, '$.ABlock.fruits1[0].Qty1) + ',' + json_value(json_col, '$.ABlock.fruits1[1].Qty1) as qty 
  from Data;
```

But I'm getting error as 'invalid number'

The output I should get is:
14
7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is oracle, the concatenation symbol is "||", not "+". The invalid number is because you are trying to sum the values "14", "," and "7" which comes down to:

```
SELECT 14 + ',' + 7 from dual;

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

This works:

```
with json_doc AS 
(SELECT
'{
    "ABlock": {
        "fruits1": [{
            "Frt1": "Apple",
            "Clr1": "Red",
            "Qty1": "14"
        }, {
            "Frt1": "Grapes",
            "Clr1": "Black",
            "Qty1": "7"
        }],
        "fruits2": [{
            "Frt2": "Pear",
            "Clr2": "Green",
            "Qty2": "9"
        }, {
            "Frt2": "Lemon",
            "Clr2": "Yellow",
            "Qty2": "5"
        }]
    }
}' AS json_col FROM dual
)
SELECT
json_value(json_col, '$.ABlock.fruits1[0].Qty1') ||' '||
json_value(json_col, '$.ABlock.fruits1[1].Qty1') 
FROM json_doc;

14 7
```

Replace the `||' '||` with `||','||` to get 14,7

Comment: Yeah it worked. Thank you.